# Copy Array of strings in C error

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, strcpy

I want to save about 20 country names into one string and then copy them to another but it always do me some mistake, can anybody help me with it?

This is my code:

```
char array1[30][30], array2[30][30];
```

This is how i put them into first array:

```
fscanf(fr, "%s", array1[i]);
```

This all works but when i want to do:

```
array2[0] = array1[0];
```

I get error:

```
incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[30]' from type 'char *'
```

When I use:

```
strcpy(array2[pom2], array1[i]);
```

it shows no error but doesn't copy it nor print it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try passing character by character?

```
for( i = 0; i < 30; i++ ){
   for( j = 0; j < 30; j++ ){
      targetArray[ i ][ j ] = sourceArray[ i ][ j ];

      /* End of the string, stop copying */
      if ( sourceArray[ i ][ j ] == '\0' ){
         break;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: This is fast not deep thinking solution

Comment: You will copy useless characters with this solution. And, that is generally slower than using `strcpy` or `memcpy`, which are usually optimized by compilers.

Comment: @Fabien, that's correct that's why I said "fast and not thinking solution"

Comment: if i use this i get about 20-30 weird chars like &@-:-/ and so on, it looks like i copy from bad source, but then i tried to print array1[0] it prints: Croatia then  i tried to do `for (i = 0; i < 30; i++){array2[0][i] = array1[0][i] }` then when i print array1[o] i get Croatia and when i print array2[o] i get again these 30 weird characters

Comment: It somehow didnt worked for me, but deleted the whole project folder just copied the code to new project and tried the strcpy again and now it worked. Thanks a lot for helping me and so fast help, much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

For the first error : you cannot copy an array into another one. You can just copy salar values (chars, in your case).

If you want to copy a string into another, you indeed have to use the `strcpy` function (or a close relative, as `strncpy`. You should give us the full code so that we can see where the problem is with your call to `strcpy`.

Comment: When i use `strcpy` it prints me something like this: !"#$%&'<>*+,-./

Comment: Did you check that `fr` is actually valid ? i.e., did you check, while opening it, that everything was OK ? If something went wrong, `fr`is `NULL` and then anything can happen.

Comment: yes i checked if its not `NULL` also checked array1[0] and printed it it prints: Croatia